# force textblock next to image

Tags: html, css

Hello i have an image and want to display text next to it. therefore i put the text inside a `<div>` element and set it to `display:inline-block`. I also have both the div and the img set to `vertical-align:middle`
Now, the `<br>` elements in the text work fine, but if a line is too long, the whole textblock is put beneath the image. Can i somehow force it to be in the same line and make linebreaks instead?
Of course i could use max-width to make sure it fits in the line, but the fact is, i can't calculate the width of the img. or can i somehow make it take up the rest of the line?

Comment: better share the code than describing it ... And this seems to be a float use case

Comment: share your code

Answer (score -1):

Add CSS attributes `float:left` to your image and `float:right` to your text box (div). CSS attribute `display:inline-block` must also be added. CSS attribute `vertical-align` will not work with float. Use display flex instead and set CSS property `align-items:center` to vertically align.

Comment: Plz help me improve my answer

Answer (score -1):

use this structure for text front of the image and when text goes to second line text start under the image. if you want text every time stay in front of image than add style p tag overflow: hidden.

```
<div style="overflow: hidden">
    <img style="float: left" src="images/imageName.png">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Why have you added the overflow attribute?

Comment: It’s interesting to note that overflow will also create a new block formatting context which is useful if we want to align a block element next to a floated one. In the example below we show how a number of paragraphs will interact with a floated image by default and then we use overflow: hidden to align the text within its own box:                                                                                                          https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting                                       https://codepen.io/robinrendle/pen/bNZmqr